# Can I search multiple HTML elements within the soup.find_all() function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website for most viewed headlines. The class selector of the text I want shares common words with other items on the page. For example, I want the text between the  tag and class "black_color". Other items use the  tag and have the class "color_black hover_color_gray_90" and I don't want these included. I was thinking I could use more HTML elements to be more specific but I'm not sure how to incorporate them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getHeadlines():
    url = "https://www.bostonglobe.com/"

    source_code = requests.get(url)

    plainText = source_code.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

    #results = soup.find_all("h2",{"class":"headline"})
    results = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"black_color"})
    

    with open("headlines.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for i in results:
            f.write(str(i.text + ' \n' + '\n'))
        

getHeadlines()
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data and the desired extracted output?  It's hard to know what you mean "I want the text between the tag and class" - a class is an attribute of a tag.  In your code, for example, you search for the `<a>` tag with the class `'black_color'`.  What does it mean to get the text between them?  And what are examples of other items that "use the tag and have the class"?

Comment: I want the text embedded here: <a class="color_black" href="/2020/09/11/metro/40-pound-exotic-pet-cat-loose-new-hampshire/?p1=HP_Feed_ContentQuery">40-pound exotic pet cat on the loose in New Hampshire</a>. This code also exists on the page and I don't want these results included in my output: <a href="/sports/?p1=BGMenu_Sections" tabindex="0" class="color_black hover_color_gray_90">Sports</a>

Answer (score 0):

I think looking at the `<a>` tag may actually be harder than using at the matching `<h2>`, which has a `'headline'` class.

Try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, "html.parser")

for headline in soup.find_all("h2", class_="headline"):
    print(headline.text)
```

Output:

```
Boston College outbreak worries epidemiologists, students, community
Nantucket finds ‘community spread’ of COVID-19 among tradespeople The town’s Select Board and Board of Health will hold an emergency meeting at 10 a.m. Monday to consider placing restrictions on some of those trades, officials said Friday. 
Weddings in a pandemic: Welcome to the anxiety vortexNewlyweds are spending their honeymoons praying they don’t hear from COVID‐19 contact tracers. Relatives are agonizing over “damned if we RSVP yes, damned if we RSVP no” decisions. Wedding planners are adding contract clauses specifying they’ll walk off the job if social distancing rules are violated. 
Fauci says US should plan to ‘hunker down’ for fall and winter
Of struggling area, Walsh says, ‘We have to get it better under control’ 
...
```

After looking at it for awhile, I think the `<a>` tag may actually have some classes added dynamically, which BS will not pick up.  Just searching for the `color_black` class and excluding the `color_black hover_color_gray_90` class yields the headline classes that you don't want (e.g. 'Sports'), even though when I look at the actual web page source code, I see it's differentiated in the way you've indicated.

That's usually a good sign that there are post-load CSS changes being made to a page.  (I may be wrong about that, but in either case I hope the `<h2>` approach gets you what you need.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you look at my code, I have the h2, class = headline part commented out to try another way. Searching for that element and class works fine, it just returns A LOT of results and includes other things I don't want. I was hoping to just scrape the 'Most Viewed' list so I only get about 10 results instead of 50+.

Comment: The Most Viewed list is dynamically rendered from some database pull, post-page-load.  That means BeautifulSoup can't see it.  You can test this - the `<div>` that contains Most Viewed has a specific `id` value, on my load that value is `c0fhKlnQperj1CT`.  So once you have the `soup` object, run: `soup.find(id="c0fhKlnQperj1CT").contents`.  You'll see there is only a `<span>` tag with a `'spacer'` class assigned.  But if you look at the HTML in the actual web page in your browser, you'll see that spacer `<span>` but also a whole bunch of extra code that loads the Most Viewed table.